# Error compiling lambda on JavaFX WorkerStateEvent

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, javafx

This code does not compile with the javac JDK8 compiler.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Test.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Service service = new Service() {
            @Override
            protected Task createTask() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        service.setOnFailed(event -> System.out.println(event.getSource().getException().toString()));
    }
}
```

The error is

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: method getException()
location: class java.lang.Object
```

IntelliJ tells me yet that all is OK and if I manually add a cast on `event.getSource()`, the compilation works but Intellij tells me that the cast is redundant.

Is there an Intellij bug ? I use the latest version of Intellij Ultimate (14.1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, I would actually write this differently. You already know what the source of the event that is fired is; it's the `service` on which you registered the listener. So you can just do

```
service.setOnFailed(event ->
        System.out.println(service.getException().toString());
```

I can't quite figure out why the compiler can't infer the types from the code you have, but if you properly type the service, providing a parameter for its generic type, then it compiles fine:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ServiceTest extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        service.setOnFailed(event ->
            System.out.println(event.getSource().getException().toString()));
    }

}
```

There's obviously enough information in your code for the compiler to infer that `event` is of type `WorkerStateEvent`, which should allow you to call `event.getSource().getException()`. I think the type inference just fails for some reason when you use raw types (`Service`) instead of generically-typed objects (`Service<Void>` etc).

Comment: Thanks but the question was more about how lambda works with generics and why intellij does not detect this error before compile phase. I was able to correct this alone.

Comment: Yes, just offering an alternative. Your original code compiles though, so this is an IntelliJ bug.

Comment: What ? You say that the code snippet I posted compiles ? I though the bug was in the autocompletion...

Comment: Ah, wait: sorry; I had modified it with an automatic change in Eclipse. Ignore that. Let me update this answer as the change is better, I think.

Comment: You were right! Thanks! I imagine it is a compiler bug so ?

Comment: This is not a bug. NetBeans does not compile the original code for the same reason. Generics must be used for the code to compile.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I had intended my earlier "ignore that" to be a correction of that statement. It seems like it's perhaps and oversight in the compiler specs, as there's no reason the generic type of Service should be required to infer types in this case, but since raw types are discouraged anyway it's probably a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `setOnFailed` is

```
public final void setOnFailed(EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> value)
```

So you need to provide an `EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>`. [`WorkerStatEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/WorkerStateEvent.html) has the method [`public Worker getSource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/WorkerStateEvent.html#getSource%28%29) that returns a [`javafx.concurrent.Worker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html).  Your lambda effectively just provides an `EventHandler<javafx.event.Event>`. The method `getSource()` of  [`javafx.event.Event`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html) just retuns a `java.util.EventObject` which does not have the method `getException()` that `WorkerStateEvent` has.

Use generics:

```
final EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> handler = event ->
  System.out.println(event.getSource().getException().toString());
service.setOnFailed(handler);
```

**Edit:**

Compiling the non-generic version with plain `javac` throws the same error:

```
src/stackoverflowfx/StackOverflowFX.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        final EventHandler handler = event -> System.out.println(event.getSource().getException().toString());
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getException()
  location: class Object
Note: src/stackoverflowfx/StackOverflowFX.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

So this is not an IDE problem.

Comment: Hum, so it seems that Intellij is a little buggy on this point because autocompletion works well with `getException()`...